# why h4 tag is not showing after using clip path on sibling div?

Tags: css

In this codepen [here on codepen](https://codepen.io/astar0n/pen/MdWrpq?editors=1100) the `h4` tag is not showing completely, above the psuedo element. I tried this psuedo selector but nothing seems to work. Am I doing anything wrong here ?

some help is appreciated.

Comment: sorry i was editing the same code.

Comment: I think it should work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the codepen link and let me know if it helps

https://codepen.io/shakcho/pen/eaYVdm

```css
.card--blue {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%; 

  .header{
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
  }

  &::after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: $color-3;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 46% 0, 81% 100%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 46% 0, 81% 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
}
```